# AWS CloudFormation InvalidNetworkInterface?

Tags: amazon-web-services, interface, aws-cloudformation

I just updated the instance type from t2.medium to t2.large.

There are three instances in the yaml, I only update one of them.

```
  ServerInstanceType:
    Description: Server EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t2.xlarge
```

Below is from CloudFormation:

```
Events (I even did not make any change on this instance):
Interface: [eni-0913d9d77ee6aacc53 in use. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidNetworkInterface.InUse; Request ID: 19e6a31c-d21c-4316-b6999e-00aece2261ca; Proxy: null)
```

Comment: Are you saying that you modified the instance type, then performed an **Update** operation on the CloudFormation stack, and then you received that error message? Do you have an Elastic IP address (or something else) associated with that instance?

Comment: I suspect that CloudFormation will attempt to totally replace that instance. It might be easier to manually Stop the instance, change the Instance Type, then Start it again.

Comment: I didn't try with CloudFormation to update instance type. On the console, If you want to change instance type, you need to stop EC2, change and start EC2 ( your public IP will be changed if you are not using EIP). I don't think your CF template can modify the instance type.

Comment: @Franxihidro You can change instance type. CFN will do what you describe on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, I did a quick test and I can modify instance type with CFN.

Comment: @baolongtougu Can you upload your CFN template and hide personal info?

Comment: @John Rotenstein, yes I only modified the instance type, then an update operation on the Cloudformation, It is wired, I remember I did this before, it was fine. But recently if I updated the instance type and tried to open a new port, I can find the same error.

Comment: @Franxi hidro, the only modification on Cloudformation is Default: t2.xlarge. Previously I did almost the same thing no error, I do not know if it's a bug from aws ?

Comment: It worked for me, I tested it yesterday, created EC2 with CFN. To modify instance type, I use update with current template then change parameter.

Comment: @Franxi hidro, OK, so you modified it directly on the ec2 yaml/json files as default, or with a related parameters json file? Thank you very much

Comment: I modifed it on parameters, like this: 
ec2InstanceType:
    Type: String
    Default: t2.medium #t3a.small #